# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') while doing KMean function

Tags: python, anaconda, data-science, k-means, sklearn-pandas

I'm new to the data science field and while practicing to do KMeans clustering I ran into this error: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

Apparently my recoding doesn't work properly because it turns my 0 to 0.0 / 1 to 1.0 etc. That's the reason why the function KMean from sklearn won't work?

[Where the recoding aka mapping fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVEhS.png)

[Where sklearn KMean fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by1Kn.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure your data does not have any nulls infinity values.

You can do:

```py
x.isnull().sum()
```

to see if there is a null values. If the sum is higher than one, this means there is at least one null value. You can treat them using fillna method:

```py
x = x.fillna(value=value_you_want_to_fill_nulls)
```

For full documentation, read: [pandas-documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Also, the other issue is probably an infinite value:

```py
np.isinf(x).sum()
# the same logic for null values

# to treat infinity you can do:
x = x.replace([np.inf, -np.inf], np.nan)
```

And then treat the null value.

But it is a good practice to understand why you are having infinity / null values and how to avoid it before doing any computation.